# Fetch binary encoded string instead of file size

Tags: python-3.x, binary, odoo-11

I want to fetch binary data encoded the string in record instead of file size string. Currently in Odoo record has a binary field with value was size string in JSON response.
Attached the screenshot of the record field value
I want to binary encoded string.

[image]

Comment: I found a solution. I posted here for others. Actually when you use search method then record return size string in the binary field but when you use browse method then its return encoded string in the record.

Comment: Hello, the same is occurring in my code, but it's strange because sometimes it's returning encoded values, but sometimes it's returning the size of the file, could you please post your code?

Comment: This help me a lot if any get this problem: self.env['...'].with_context({'active_test':True}).search(...)

Comment: @JovaniMartinez sorry for late reply.Here I pasted code for reference: rec = self.env[self._name].with_context({}).browse(record.id)
            binary_data = rec.x_retail_photo_1